# Angular 2: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm trying to implement Dynamic Forms in Angular 2. I've added additional functionalities like Delete and Cancel to the dynamic forms.
I've followed this documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

[image]

I've made some changes to the code. I'm getting error here.

How do i make this error go?

You can find the full code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SL949g1hQQrnRUr1XXqt?p=preview , which is working in plunker but not in my local system.

Html code:

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="form">

    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
      <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
            [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" [(ngModel)]="question.value">

    <select [id]="question.key" [(ngModel)]="question.value" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key" >
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [ngValue]="opt.key" >{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>

    <input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'"  [(ngModel)]="question.value"
            [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" (change)="question.value = ck.checked" #ck [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

  </div> 
  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!form.controls[question.key].valid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="clear()">Clear</button>

    </div>
  </form>

  <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
    <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Component code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';
import { QuestionBase }                 from './question-base';
import { QuestionControlService }       from './question-control.service';
import { ControlGroup }     from '@angular/common';
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/dynamicform/form.component.html',
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  providers:  [QuestionControlService]
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
  form: FormGroup;
  payLoad:any;
  payLoad2:any;
  questiont: QuestionBase<any>;
  questiond: QuestionBase<any>;
  constructor(private qcs: QuestionControlService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
    console.log("Form Init",this.questions);
    this.questiont = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.questions));
    this.questiond = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.questions));
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
    this.payLoad2=this.payLoad;
    this.questiont = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.questions));
    console.log("Submitted data",this.questions);
  }
  cancel(){
    console.log("Canceled");
    this.questions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.questiont));
  }
  clear(){
    this.questions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.questiond));
    this.questiont = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.questiond));
    console.log("Cleared");
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same error after upgrading. Will write here if I find why.

Comment: Alright, for me it disappeared when I imported the FormsModule in my NgModule declaration. But I still have an error saying "AppComponent has no route config." even if I've imported the routes. But check if it fix your problem.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49628169/6597375

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Figured out quick solution, update your @NgModule code like this :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Source: [Can’t bind to ‘ngModel’ since it isn’t a known property of ‘input’](https://wmnitin.dev/tutorials/solution-cant-bind-ngmodel-since-isnt-known-property-input/)

Comment: It is this still the correct solution? Everything for me is like this and still I am getting the error?

Comment: Yeah its still working, you can also try ReactiveFormsModule instead of FormsModule. Please post your error if any.

Comment: I am sorry. My issue was something slightly different. I figured that out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form   Thanks for reply!

Comment: It appears that the real answer was that you need to import the `FormsModule` in the same `NgModule` that you have declared your component in. Simple saying "make your NgModule look like this" is not a very good answer.

Comment: It does not work actually, it has to be the ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: It works if you have the above modules in the shown order.  Particularly, AppComponent seems to need to come after FormsModule.  This was the only change I made to resolve the same issue.

Comment: It worked for me on Ionic 4 with Angular 7. Thank you!

Comment: Also be certain you include FormsModule under imports, not declarations as I had mistakenly done.

Comment: thanks, I forgot to add component in declaration section

Answer (score 55):

In order to make ngModel  work when using AppModules  (NgModule ), you have to import FormsModule  in your AppModule .

Like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You need to add FormsModule to imports in the module where you're using its directives: In all of them right?

Answer (score 12):

I encountered a similar error after upgrading to RC5; i.e. Angular 2: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

The code on Plunker show you using Angular2 RC4, but the example code at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html is using NGModule which is part of RC5. NGModules is a breaking change from RC4 to RC5.

This page explains the migration from RC4 to RC5: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html

I hope this addresses the error you're getting and help get you going in the right direction.

In short, I had to create an NGModule in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I then changed main.ts to use the module:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Of course, I also needed to update the dependencies in package.json. Here's my dependencies from package.json. Admittedly, I've hobbled them together from other sources (maybe the ng docs examples), so your mileage may vary:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
...
```

I hope this helps better. :-)

Comment: I edited the answer to include specific code examples.

Answer (score 11):

```
import {FormControl,FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

import {FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

You should also add the missing ones.

Comment: Hi, in my case this is a solution, it seems that the Form group is an important part.

Answer (score 9):

You have just add `FormsModule` and import the `FormsModule` in your `app.module.ts` file.

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule 
],
```

Just add the above two lines in your `app.module.ts`. It's working fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to import FormsModule in your @NgModule Decorator, @NgModule is present in your moduleName.module.ts file.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule
   ],
   declarations: [ AppComponent ],
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
 })
```

Answer (score 4):

Step to follow

1. Open your `app.module.ts` file.

.

2. Add `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

.

3. Add `FormsModule`   to `imports` as`imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule  ],`

.

Final result will look like this

```
.....
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
.....
@NgModule({
.....
  imports: [   
     BrowserModule, FormsModule 
  ],
.....
})
```

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use `'ngModule'`, the `'FormsModule'` (from `@angular/forms`) needs to be added to your `import[]` array in the `AppModule` (should be there by default in a CLI project).

Answer (score 3):

First import FormsModule from angular lib and under NgModule declared it in imports

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import @angular/forms dependency to your module.

if you are using npm, install the dependency :

```
npm install @angular/forms --save
```

Import it to your module :

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
    imports: [.., FormsModule,..],
    declarations: [......],
    bootstrap: [......]
})
```

And if you are using SystemJs for loading modules

```
'@angular/forms': 'node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
```

Now you can use [(ngModel)] for two ways databinding.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason in Angular 6 simply importing the FormsModule did not fix my issue. What finally fixed my issue was by adding

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
})

export class MyClass{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Let’s assume, your old app.module.ts may look similar to this :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**Now import FormsModule in your app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

http://jsconfig.com/solution-cant-bind-ngmodel-since-isnt-known-property-input/

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help you if you are using Karma:

I've did exactly as it's mentioned in @wmnitin's answer, but the error was always there. When use "ng serve" instead of "karma start", it works ！

Answer (score 0):

It's described on the Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#the-missing-formsmodule

You have to import `FormsModule` and add it to imports in your `@NgModule` declaraction.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DynamicConfigComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got resolution for the error 2 ways to get solve.
1--check formsmodule registered or not under imports in app module/custom module.
2--check current component registered or not in custom module.
most of results/solutions explores only formsmodule ignoring current component reg in custom module or app module.
i hope this content helpful to you guys.......

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!