# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input

I have this simple input in my component which uses `[(ngModel)]` :

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" placeholder="foo" />
```

And I get the following error when I launch my app, even if the component is not displayed.

> zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Here is the component.ts:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Intervention } from '../../model/intervention';

@Component({
   selector: 'intervention-details',
   templateUrl: 'app/intervention/details/intervention.details.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/intervention/details/intervention.details.css']
})
    
export class InterventionDetails
{
   @Input() intervention: Intervention;
    
   public test : string = "toto";
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem since they updated to rc5 yesterday (interestingly it works for my colleague..) I think @abreneliere is talking about their tutorials  - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: Yes I referred to the Tour of heroes tutorial because it does use a ngModel.

Comment: I'm just staring Angular and saw this error when doing the Tour of Heroes tutorial.  Sure enough, they now [call this out in the very next line](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#the-missing-formsmodule) and tell you how/why to correct it.

Comment: It uses the same fix for textarea too

Comment: For what it's worth, I encountered this error in IONIC-4 ( 4.11.0 ) when working with Forms Validation.  If I do nothing else except add formControlName="myControl" to any <ion-input> anywhere in the form, I get the ngModel binding error message. Alternate properties, like formControlName1="myControl" do not cause this error.

Comment: If you get that error message only when running tests, see the related question [angular2 testing: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584534/angular2-testing-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-in)

Comment: This error can also be caused by not importing the module that's attempting to use `ngModel` into appModule. Say you have  `secondModule`, and `thirdModule` and you import only `secondModule` into `appModule` and you import `thirdModule` into `secondModule` and then `thirdModule` trys to use `ngModel`, you'll get this error until you import `thirdModule` into `appModule`.

Comment: Everyone says that you need the FormsModule in app.module.ts file. I only have one module and it is defined in there but I get the same message. If I remove the ngModel from the input statement it works fine. I am on Angular 12 - has that changed?

Answer (score 2882, accepted):

Yes, that's it. In the *app.module.ts* file, I just added:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

[...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]
    FormsModule
  ],
  [...]
})
```

Comment: Actually, I prefer this Answer to Gabriele's  (which is just a link).  Here, the exact code is presented.   Annoyingly, I hit this problem just following John Paps's "Introduction to Angular 2" on PluralSight, and this issue wasn't even mentioned.  For them, the 2-way binding just worked.

Comment: This worked, but only after I imported it into my sub-module. It's not completely clear to beginners that this doesn't get inherited by sub-modules.

Comment: In my case, My use of braces were wrong. I was using `[{ngModel}]` instead of the correct one: `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: For those who find this because of a similar failure with Jasmine, you'll need to add these imports to the `component.spec.ts` file as well.

Comment: And for where to put it (regarding the Jasmine error): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584534/angular2-testing-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-in#answer-39584550

Comment: This error does also happen in tests. If that is your problem, you also have to import the `FormsModule` into your TestBed, similar to Anthonys solution: `TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: […Component],
      imports: [
        FormsModule
      ]
    })`

Comment: @adam0101 because as you may know the FormsModule is used in the component, right? and components have local scope, not global one. that's why you need to imported it there. 
There are some modules (such as services) that have global scope which don't need to be imported to every nested component's module.

Comment: @Imtiaz remember "banana in a box": `[()]` *not* mustaches in a box `[{}]`...gross! https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: The FormModule import must be added into the module where you are trying to use the directive ngModel.

Comment: I am happy to announce this solution is covered by Assistant https://medium.com/@tomaszs2/mapping-stackoverflow-into-real-time-assistance-e627dda88f69

Comment: I didn't knew that [(ngModel)] is case sensitive, I wasted a lot of time, done everything and in the end it came out that I was using [(ngmodel)] all in small

Answer (score 680):

In order to be able to use two-way data binding for form inputs you need to import the `FormsModule` package in your Angular module.

For more information, see the Angular 2 official tutorial [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html#!#two-way-binding) and the official documentation for [forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).

Comment: I have to admit that I start with Angular on Monday (so 4 days ago) and was doing their tutorials so I'm pretty sure I did something wrong but for me importing FormsModule didn't work. Then I added  `import { FORM_DIRECTIVES }    from '@angular/forms';` and added the `FORM_DIRECTIVES` to directives and yeah my binding is working again (to be clear it was working before rc5 release)

Comment: Which seems to be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623879/angular-2-two-way-binding-using-ng-model-is-not-working

Comment: @PetLahev the issue you're having with the tutorial is that on August 7th, when you started, the tutorials were running Release Candidate 4. As of August 8th, they are at Release Candidate 5, which has different syntax

Comment: Imported angular Forms along with FORM_DIRECTIVES saved me.. :)

Comment: `FORM_DIRECTIVES` are dead just in case

Comment: It's worth nothing that, if you are using a SharedModule, you might need to import FormsModule there aswell.

Answer (score 305):

For using `[(ngModel)]` in **Angular 2**, **4** & **5+**, you need to import **FormsModule** from Angular form...

Also, it is in this path under forms in the **Angular repository** on **GitHub**:

> **angular / packages / forms / src / directives / ng_model.ts**

Probably this is not a very pleasurable for the **AngularJS developers** as you could use **ng-model** everywhere anytime before, but as Angular tries to separate modules to use whatever you'd like you to want to use at the time, **ngModel** is in **FormsModule** now.

Also, if you are using **ReactiveFormsModule** it needs to import it too.

So simply look for **app.module.ts** and make sure you have `FormsModule` imported in...

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  // <<<< import it here
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule // <<<< And here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Also, these are the current starting comments for Angular4 `ngModel` in **FormsModule**:

````
/**
 * `ngModel` forces an additional change detection run when its inputs change:
 * E.g.:
 * ```
 * <div>{{myModel.valid}}</div>
 * <input [(ngModel)]="myValue" #myModel="ngModel">
 * ```
 * I.e. `ngModel` can export itself on the element and then be used in the template.
 * Normally, this would result in expressions before the `input` that use the exported directive
 * to have and old value as they have been
 * dirty checked before. As this is a very common case for `ngModel`, we added this second change
 * detection run.
 *
 * Notes:
 * - this is just one extra run no matter how many `ngModel` have been changed.
 * - this is a general problem when using `exportAs` for directives!
 */
````

If you'd like to use your input, not in a form, you can use it with `ngModelOptions` and make standalone **true**...

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

For more information, look at **ng_model** in the Angular section [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.4/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts).

Answer (score 136):

You need to import the FormsModule.

Open **app.module.ts** and add the lines

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       FormsModule
    ],
})
```

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 114):

To resolve We must include `FormModule` in the `app.module.ts` file to avoid the `Can't bind to ngModel as it isn't a known property of the input` problem in Angular apps.

The steps are as follows,

Open `app.module.ts` and **add** the import line

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and **add** `FormsModule` to `imports`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       FormsModule
    ],
})
```

Figure 1.0 (app.module.ts file)

[image]

Comment: 100% requires the FormsModule to be imported. Fixed the Issue for me.

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Comment: Importing the Mocked version is enough: MockModule(FormsModule)

Answer (score 71):

Assuming you have created a new NgModule, say `AuthModule` dedicated to handling your authentication needs, make sure to import `FormsModule` in that AuthModule **too**.

If you'll be using the `FormsModule` *only* in the `AuthModule` then you wouldn't need to import the `FormModule` *in* the default `AppModule`.

So something like this in the `AuthModule`:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { authRouting } from './auth.routing';
import { LoginComponent, SignupComponent } from './auth.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    authRouting,
    FormsModule
   ],
  declarations: [
    SignupComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Then forget about importing in `AppModule` if you don't use the `FormsModule` anywhere else.

Comment: I needed it at sub-module where I was using the Form features. Higher up the hierarchy was not sufficient.

Answer (score 53):

Simple solution: In file *app.module.ts* -

#### Example 1

```
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
// Add in imports

imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 FormsModule
 ],
```

#### Example 2

If you want to use [(ngModel)] then you have to import  FormsModule in *app.module.ts*:

```
import { FormsModule  } from "@angular/forms";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, videoComponent, tagDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,  FormsModule

  ],
  providers: [ApiServices],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Where exactly is the difference in the two examples?

Comment: in my case, had to import FormsModule on my component.module.ts

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 53):

Import the FormsModule in those modules where you want to use the [(ngModel)]

[image]

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Comment: @MartinSchneider then how its having this upvotes :)

Comment: My guess: the default design by SO that shows more recent and trending answers above older ones and the fact that most users are lazy ;)

Comment: is this works? if yes then close the topic :) @MartinSchneider

Answer (score 51):

There are two steps you need to follow to get rid of this error:

1. import FormsModule in your app module
2. Pass it as value of imports in @NgModule decorator

Basically, file *app.module.ts* should look like below:

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
    import {AppChildComponent} from './appchild.component';
    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, AppChildComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd not declared it in the imports section and it was driving me insane when I moved a component into a sub-module.

Answer (score 50):

Sometimes, even though we are already imported `BrowserModule`, `FormsModule` and other related modules, we still may get the same *error*.

Then I realized that we need to ***import them in order***, which is missed in my case. So the order should be like  `BrowserModule`, `FormsModule`, and `ReactiveFormsModule`.

As per my understanding, *feature modules* should follow the *basic modules* of Angular.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You have ReactiveFormsModule  in your imports array, but not in your imports. just saying.

Comment: Is there a way to find out the order?  i.e. If we have a few more modules to import, how do I confirm the sequence?

Comment: As per my understanding, Feature Modules should follow the Basic Modules of Angular. In case of Feature Modules sequence, we don't need to worry because our Error cause is not related to them.

Comment: 2021 reporting in, to mention that `FormsModule` **must** be imported after `NgModule`. This error will appear otherwise. This answer is the only one that mentions the importance of the order!

Comment: You don't need ReactiveFormsModule when using template driven forms :-> Order irrelevant.

Answer (score 39):

I am using Angular 7.

I have to import ReactiveFormsModule, because I am using the FormBuilder class to create a reactive form.

```
import {
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ], declarations: []})
```

Answer (score 36):

You need to import **FormsModule** in your **root** module if this component is in the root i.e. **app.module.ts**

Kindly open app.module.ts

Import **FormsModule** from **@angular/forms**

Ex:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
   FormsModule
],
})
```

Comment: A slight extension to [PRao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input/52675849#52675849).

Answer (score 33):

Import **FormsModule** in you app module.

It would let your application run well.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {ContactListCopmponent} from './contacts/contact-list.component';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,ContactListCopmponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 27):

I'm using Angular 5.

In my case, I needed to import ReactiveFormsModule too.

File *app.module.ts* (or *anymodule.module.ts*):

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

Comment: `ReactiveFormsModule` is required when you need `FormGroup, FormControl ,Validators` etc. For using `ngModel`, you don't require `ReactiveFormsModule`.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Adding ReactiveFormModule is the only thing that made the error go away in my case.  I'm using Angular 7.

Comment: Looks like the latest versions of Angular requires the ReactiveFormsModule to be imported for the ngModel to work. I was trained on Angular 7 and the same when I practiced it did not work, because I had the latest @angular/cli in my machine. After adding this ReactiveFormsModule, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 23):

If someone is still getting errors after applying the accepted solution, it could be possibly because you have a separate module file for the component in which you want to use the ngModel property in input tag. In that case, apply the accepted solution in the component's module.ts file as well.

Comment: That was already mentioned in an [answer from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 23):

I know this question is about Angular 2, but I am on Angular 4 and none of these answers helped.

In Angular 4 the syntax needs to be

```
[(ngModel)]
```

Answer (score 19):

If you are still getting the error after importing FormsModule correctly then check in your terminal or (windows console) because your project is not compiling (because of another error that could be anything) and your solution has not been reflected in your browser!

In my case, my console had the following unrelated error:

> Property 'retrieveGithubUser' does not exist on type 'ApiService'.

Comment: What is the action to be taken (after checking)? Please respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45333055/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar).

Comment: Peter, you don't seem to comprehend my answer. When I say "could be anything" means that after checking the error, the universe of actions to be taken are unlimited. My answer has been upvoted 17 times, which means that many developers found my answer complete and there is no need for an edit.

Answer (score 18):

#### Import FormModule in file *app.module*

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; [...] @NgModule({ imports: [ [...] FormsModule ], [...] })
```

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 16):

**ngModel** is coming from FormsModule. There are some cases when you can receive this kind of error:

1. You didn't import the FormsModule into the import array of modules where your component is declared - the component in which the ngModel is used.
2. You have import the FormsModule into one module which is inherited of another module. In this case you have two options:

- let the FormsModule be imported into the import array from both modules:module1 and module2. **As the rule:  Importing a module does *not* provide access to its imported modules. (Imports are not inherited)**

  [image]
- declare the FormsModule into the import and export arrays in module1 to be able to see it in model2 also

  [image]

3. (In some version I faced this problem) You have imported the FormsModule correctly, but the problem is on the input HTML tag. You must add the name tag attribute for the input, and the object bound name in [(ngModel)] must be the same as the name into the *name* attribute

   [image]

Answer (score 16):

You need to import the FormsModule in app.module.ts and add the lines

```
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
       
        FormsModule
      ]
    })
```

The ngModel directive declared in the FormsModule lets you bind controls in your template-driven form to properties in your data model. When you include the directive using the syntax for two-way data binding, [(ngModel)], Angular can track the value and user interaction of the control and keep the view synced with the model.

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 15):

In the module you are willing to use **ngModel** you have to import **FormsModule**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
  ],

})
export class AbcModule { }
```

Comment: I was missing this in my app.module.ts, thank you Malindu!

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 14):

In `ngModule` you need to import `FormsModule`, because `ngModel` is coming from `FormsModule`.
Please modify your **app.module.ts** like the below code I have shared

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
         AppComponent,
         HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
         BrowserModule,
         AppRoutingModule,
         FormsModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same problem and the reason was that I was using ngModel in my `MenuComponent`. I imported my `MenuComponent in app.module.ts`, but I forgot to add it to `declarations` array.

[image: Error]

Declaring the MenuComponent solved my issue. I.e., as shown in the below image:

[image: Solved issue]

Comment: That has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616267/1951524) already

Answer (score 11):

For my scenario, I had to import both [CommonModule] and [FormsModule] to my module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core' 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 

import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyComponent 
    ]
 }) 
export class MyModule { }
```

Answer (score 11):

**ngModel** should be imported from **@angular/forms** because it is the part of FormsModule. So I advice you to change your app.module.ts in something like this:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

[...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]
    FormsModule
  ],
  [...]
})
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 11):

You need to import the FormsModule.

```
#Open app.module.ts
#add the lines

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
and

@NgModule({
    imports: [
       FormsModule   <--------add this 
    ],
})


if you are using reactive form then also added  ReactiveFormsModule
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't add much value to the chosen one.

Comment: @FrancescoColamonici or the other 17 answers with the exact same solution.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes you get this error when you try to use a component from a module, which is not shared, in a different module.

For example, you have 2 modules with module1.componentA.component.ts and module2.componentC.component.ts and you try to use the selector from module1.componentA.component.ts in a template inside module2 (e.g. `<module1-componentA [someInputVariableInModule1]="variableFromHTTPRequestInModule2">`),  it will throw the error that the someInputVariableInModule1 is not available inside module1.componentA.component.ts - even though you have the `@Input() someInputVariableInModule1` in the module1.componentA.

If this happens, you want to share the module1.componentA to be accessible in other modules.
So if you share the module1.componentA inside a sharedModule, the module1.componentA will be usable inside other modules (outside from module1), and every module importing the sharedModule will be able to access the selector in their templates injecting the `@Input()` declared variable.

Comment: I have this exact problem, and you say, you should share the module so you can use componentA in ComponentC. But.. How do I share the module1? Which is the sintax to "share a module"? I guessed exporting module1 and then importing it in the module2 was enough sharing, but still having this problem

Comment: So to answer myself, this is how you share a module https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-di-tree.html

Comment: Hey sorry i didn't see your comment that fast :) Yes, this is how you can create a SharedModule and import your own modules there, which you want to use in multiple other modules. Then you import the SharedModule where you want to use the module which is imported in the shared one.

Answer (score 9):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule     
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: Furthermore this answer does not add any value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524)

Answer (score 9):

#### Angular 14+ Using Standalone Component

Import the form component directly into your standalone component:

```
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgFor } from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-view',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ 
    NgFor,
    FormsModule
    ],  
  templateUrl: './table-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-view.component.css']
})
```

Comment: Or not make the component standalone.

Answer (score 8):

This is for the folks who use plain JavaScript instead of Type Script. In addition to referencing the forms script file on top of the page like below:

```
<script src="node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js"></script>
```

You should also tell the the module loader to load the `ng.forms.FormsModule`. After making the changes my `imports` property of `NgModule` method looked like below:

`imports: [ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, ng.forms.FormsModule],`

Answer (score 7):

I upgraded from RC1 to RC5 and received this error.

I completed my migration (introducing a new `app.module.ts` file, changing `package.json` to include new versions and missing modules, and finally changing my `main.ts` to boot accordingly, based on the [Angular2 quick start example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)).

I did an `npm update` and then an `npm outdated` to confirm the versions installed were correct, still no luck.

I ended up completely wiping the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling with `npm install` - Voila! Problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

Actually in most of the cases the `FormsModule` was already imported. So what you have to do is you have to make sure that

1. Your component is properly added in the declarations array in app.module.ts file.
2. You should verify that the binding was well spelled. The correct spelling is `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was, I forgot to declare the component in the declarations array of the module.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [yourcomponentName]
})
```

Comment: That has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616267/1951524) already

Answer (score 5):

When I first did the tutorial, main.ts looked slightly different from what it is now. It looks very similar, but note the differences (the top one is correct).

Correct:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Old tutorial code:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 5):

Combining all the possible solutions :

1. Check if your typing it correctly. It should be "[(ngModel)]" with "M" capital.
2. Check if you have import FormsModule in your TS file.If not, you can do it like this :

In app.module.ts, add these lines

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    xyz,
    abc,
    FormsModule
  ],
})
```

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524) and others.

Comment: @MartinSchneider I've already mentioned on the top. I've compiled them for easier access and save some time :)

Answer (score 4):

For any version from Angular 2, you need to import FormsModule in your app.module.ts file and it will fix the issue.

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 4):

Recently I found that mistake happened not only in case when you forgot to import FormsModule in your module. In my case problem was in this code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName"
                   formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name"
                   value={{user.firstName}} [(ngModel)]="user.firstName">
```

I fix it with change **formControlName** -> **name**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName"
                   name="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name"
                   value={{user.firstName}} [(ngModel)]="user.firstName">
```

Comment: Yes Nikita the "name" property is also required for the template-driven approach to forms. The name property is used by the angular form directive to assign validation errors, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Though the answer solves the issue, I would like to provide a little more information on this topic as I have also undergone this issue when I started to work on Angular projects.

A beginner should understand that there are two main types of forms. They are Reactive forms and Template-driven forms. From [Angular 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) onward, it is recommended to use **Reactive forms** for any kind of forms.

Reactive forms are more robust: they're more scalable, reusable, and testable. If forms are a key part of your application, or you're already using reactive patterns for building your application, use reactive forms.

Template-driven forms are useful for adding a simple form to an application, such as an email list signup form. They're easy to add to an application, but they don't scale as well as reactive forms. If you have very basic form requirements and logic that can be managed solely in the template, use template-driven forms.

Refer [Angular documents](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) for more details.

Coming to the question, `[(ngModel)]="..."` is basically a binding syntax. In order to use this in your component HTML page, you should import **FormsModule** in your **NgModule** (where your component is present). Now `[(ngModel)]` is used for a simple two-way binding or this is used in your form for any input HTML element.

On the other hand, to use reactive forms, import `ReactiveFormsModule` from the `@angular/forms` package and add it to your NgModule's imports array.

For example, if my component HTML content does not have [(ngmodel)] in any HTML element, then I don't need to import FormsModule.

In my below example, I have completely used Reactive Forms and hence I don't need to use FormsModule in my NgModule.

Create GroupsModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GroupsRoutingModule, routedAccountComponents } from './groups-routing.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        routedAccountComponents
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        GroupsRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot()
    ]
})
export class GroupsModule {
}
```

Create the routing module (separated to main the code and for readability):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GroupsComponent } from './all/index.component';
import { CreateGroupComponent } from './create/index.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'groups',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'groups',
    component: GroupsComponent
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class GroupsRoutingModule { }


export const routedAccountComponents = [
  GroupsComponent,
  CreateGroupComponent
];
```

CreateGroupComponent html code

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <label for="name">Group Name</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

CreateGroupComponent ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogResult } from 'src/app/shared/modal';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { validateAllFormFields } from 'src/app/services/validateAllFormFields';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { modelStateFormMapper } from 'src/app/services/shared/modelStateFormMapper';
import { GroupsService } from '../groups.service';
import { CreateGroup } from '../model/create-group.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-group',
    templateUrl: './index.component.html',
    providers: [LoadingService]
})

export class CreateGroupComponent implements OnInit {
    public form: FormGroup;
    public errors: string[] = [];
    private destroy: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(
        private groupService: GroupsService,
        private toastr: ToastrService
    ) { }

    private buildForm(): FormGroup {
        return new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(254)])
        });
    }

    private getModel(): CreateGroup {
        const formValue = this.form.value;
        return <CreateGroup>{
            name: formValue.name
        };
    }

    public control(name: string): AbstractControl {
        return this.form.get(name);
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.buildForm();
    }


    public onSubmit(): void {

         if (this.form.valid) {
             // this.onSubmit();
             //do what you need to do
         }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps developers to understand as to why and when you need to use **FormsModule**.

Answer (score 4):

This error will happen too even if the `FormsModule` is imported directly or indirectly (from a shared module for example) in the feature module, if the imported component is not declared on `declarations`:

[image]

I followed Deborah Kurata's Angular Routing course. While I added the imported component **ProductEditInfoComponent** on Angular Route's `component` property, I forgot to add ProductEditInfoComponent on `declarations` property.

Adding the ProductEditInfoComponent on the declarations property would solve the **NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.** problem:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Main reason of this error is you forget to import FormsModule in your app.module.ts.

But sometimes in big projects you may forget add your component in its module and confront this error.

Comment: That has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616267/1951524) already

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error when running my Angular tests because FormsModule was not added in the specification file.

We need to add it in all specification files whereas for the application to run successfully we will add at one place in the *app.module.ts* file.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure for the template-driven forms approach (https://angular.io/guide/forms), as has already been mentioned by @Nikita Sychou, you have decorated the input field with the "name" property, eg

```
<form>
   <input [(ngModel)]="form.email" name="email"></input>
```

and that the FormsModule has been imported in the associated @NgModule. Both are preconditions for avoiding the "Can't bind to ngModel" errors. If you still get styling errors in your IDE e.g. IntelliJ complaining about the ngModel directive just ignore them.. you are good to go :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was forgetting to add the component that uses the forms module tools in my app.module declarations. Without this the application's import scope will not recognize the component and will not be able to use it.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent <-- component that implements forms module
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Remember that the ngModel directive is defined as a part of Angular FormsModule and you need to include FormsModule in the imports: [...] section of the Angular module metadata, in which you want to use it.

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [

    FormsModule
  ],

})
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 9 and I have a '<form' tag with the [formGroup] property. I also had an '<input' tag specifying a button, which caused the error on the [(ngModel)] part.

I resolved the error by just removing only that (ngModel) part.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use two way binding in Angular you need to import the **FormsModule** package into your module.

You do this by adding FormsModule to the imports array inside your module (e.g. app.module.ts) like this.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    FormsModule     <-------
  ],
  [...]
})
```

Comment: This answer adds no further value over the answers from 2016:
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894463/1951524), [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1951524), [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676661/1951524)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error even that I added FormsModule as described above. So just a simple restart was required to finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [(ngModel)] is actually spelled 'ngModel' with Capital M.. I lost some minutes for not seeing this

Comment: correct , I mistakenly used `[(ng-model)]` , i used `[(ngModel)]` and it work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a famous error in Angular occurs in Angular when you are trying to use the "ngModel" directive on an "input" element, but the "ngModel" directive is not recognized as a property of the "input" element.
The solution, is to import the "FormsModule" in your application and include it in the "imports" array of your module. like this:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
imports: [
FormsModule,
// other imports
],
// other properties
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried everything above, and more and still cannot solve it, read this.

I spent a long time finding the solution these errors too! And they are showing up on almost all html.

If

- you recently updated your angular version
- and vs code (sometimes) gives an error `popup angular extension might not work correctly because ngcc operation failed`

The solution is: **to update `Angular Language Service` extension** to. That's it!

Other related solutions I have come along but didn't solve my problems will be listed below. Maybe you have a different problem:

- adding CommonModule, or `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]` in the component
- adding BrowserModule, or checking errors in app.module.ts
- checking "target" version in tsconfig.json

Happy coding!