# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' despite importing FormsModule

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am following the [Angular 2 tutorial on MVA](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-angular-20-16540?l=X8aVPdyfC_8806218965). I can't seem to get the two way binding to work. I applied the fix in [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input) but this isn't working. The error is below:

> ```
> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
>         <p>
>             <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="sampleText" ><br/>
>             <span>{{sampleText}}</span>
>         </p>
> "): TasksComponent@2:19 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ;
> ```

My `main.ts` code is as follows:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // supposed fix


@Component({
    selector: 'tasks',
    template: `
        <p>
            <input [(ngModel)]="sampleText" ><br/>
            <span>{{sampleText}}</span>
        </p>
    `
})
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {
    sampleText: string = "";
    ngOnInit() {}
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [TasksComponent],
    template: `
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <tasks></tasks>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The code works if I comment out the two way binding. How can I fix this?

Comment: what version of Angular RC you are using? IF RC5 can you add the root NgModule?

Comment: I am using RC5. I haven't created any module. The main.ts is the only file I created in my app folder.

Comment: Did you try the supposed fix, does it works?

Comment: You need to create a root NgModule in which you import the FormsModule

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use below,

```
 import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 // Import and use below directive
 import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms'; 


 @Component({
    selector: 'tasks',
    template: `
     <p>
        <input [(ngModel)]="sampleText" ><br/>
        <span>{{sampleText}}</span>
     </p>
   `
   , directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
 })
 export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {
   sampleText: string = "";

   constructor() {}
 
   ngOnInit() {}
 }

 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   directives: [TasksComponent],
   template: `
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <tasks></tasks>
    `
 })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() {}

   ngOnInit() {}
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/aVmZIY?p=preview)

However you should consider using `NgModule`, and import the `FormsModule` in it.