# How to properly connect the ng2-datepicker component in angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ng2-datepicker

[Ng2-datepicker](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker) (1.0.6)
Angular2 (2.0.0-rc.5)

When i try to use it in html as in their docs i got this error:

```
    zone.js:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'datepicker'.
    ("
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <datepicker [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="notice.date"></datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
    "): AddNoticeComponent@17:24 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to `declarations: [...]` of an `@NgModule()` and also add `imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]` to this `@NgModule()`

Comment: Thanks to your answer i found that actually the problem is not in connecting Ng2-Datepicker, but in the NgModel itself. I tried solutions described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input) and nothing helps.

Comment: Actually a complete wipe of node_modules and after 'npm install' it works correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in .ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [   
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
})
```