# Binding the value in a textarea

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

I'm trying to do the simplest two way binding in Angular2. I would like to share a variable between my component and it's template.

My template is:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="currentQuery"></textarea>
```

And my component is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'vs-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent {
    private currentQuery: string = '';
}
```

According to the docs this should work but I'm getting:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'. ("
    <div class="query-bar-container">
        <textarea [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="currentQuery"></textarea>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click"): HomeComponent@2:15
```

Comment: See also [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/603003).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
      /* BrowserModule or CommonModule */, 
      FormsModule /* or RectiveFormsModule */]
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already imported that in my root `app.module`, I thought that would be enough for the whole application, but clearly not.

Comment: No, you need that in every module where you want to use directives of other modules. (`BrowserModule` is only for the `app.module`, `CommonModule` for all others). It's enough to import modules that only provide services once in the root module but not for directives.

Comment: Where do you import the browser module from?

Comment: `@angular/platform-browser` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/BrowserModule-class.html

Comment: For me, BrowserModule didn't work, but FormsModule did as mentioned in [this answer] as well.

Comment: @ComFreek Thanks. That changed a bit since then.