# angular2 testing: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: testing, angular, angular-cli, angular2-testing

I am trying to test angular2 two-way binding for control `input`. Here is the error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

The app.component.html

```html
<input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />
<div id="divName">{{name}}</div>
```

The app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'  
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;    
}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```js
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
describe('App: Cli', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers:[AppService]
    });
  });

  it('divName', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    comp.name = 'test';
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;    
    expect(compiled.querySelector('divName').textContent).toContain('test');
  }));  
});
```

Answer (score 271, accepted):

You need to import the `FormsModule` into the `TestBed` configfuration.

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ FormsModule ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers:[AppService]
});
```

What you are doing with the `TestBed` is configuring a NgModule from scratch for the test environment. This allows you to only add what is needed for the test without having unnecessary outside variables that may affect the test.

Comment: This angular stuff seems so random.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Agreed, @PeteB.   Dependency injection is so great.... it does everything for you automagically... JUST DONT FORGET TO IMPORT HERE AND NO_ERROR_SCHEMA and yada yda...

Comment: This got rid of my error, but it hangs in Karma and doesn't continue creating the other components after. It is stuck now with no error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, even after importing forms module this was not solved. So I had to use alternative to ngModel for text field. Please check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22606):

In summary i had used [value] to bind the model for the text field like this.

```html
([value])="searchTextValue"
```

Also,if you are using date field you need to bind the model in ts. in the html, call the method

```html
(dateSelect)="onDateSelect($event)"
```

In the type script, use the following code.This is applicable only if you are using Ngbdate picker.

```js
onDateSelect(event) {
  let year = event.year;
  let month = event.month <= 9 ? '0' + event.month : event.month;;
  let day = event.day <= 9 ? '0' + event.day : event.day;;
  let finalDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  this.finalDateVlaue = finalDate;
}
```

Comment: This saved me a ton of time.  All of these quirks in Angular test beds.  Driving me nuts.