# Angular 2 - Checked property of radio button on load when it is binded by ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to check a radio button on load of the page, which is also two-way binded. It is only happening when the ngModel is removed.

```
<input [(ngModel)] = "field.value" name="{{field.label}}" type="radio"
             [checked]="option.isDefaultOption=='true'?'true':null"/>
```

Comment: You might want to check this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214655/angular-2-checkbox-two-way-data-binding

Comment: Yes. I saw that question too, before posting. But the solution asks me to make it one-way binding. Am checking if I can achieve that with 2-way binding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in component

```
ngOnInit() {

   field.value = true;

}
```

and in the template

```
 <input [(ngModel)] = "field.value" name="{{field.label}}" type="radio"
         [value]="true" />
```