# Checkbox data binding in Angular 2 and TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have HTML view like below where user's roles are checked. I would like to bind table of changed user's roles using `actualizeRoles()` method. How can I do that?

```
<md-accordion class="example-headers-align">
        <md-expansion-panel hideToggle="true" *ngFor="let userRole of userRoles">
            <md-expansion-panel-header>
                <md-panel-title>
                    {{userRoles.UserName}}
                </md-panel-title>
                <md-panel-description>
                    {{userRoles.RoleName}}
                </md-panel-description>
            </md-expansion-panel-header>
            <div *ngFor="let role of roles">
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="userRoles.RoleIds == role.Id">{{r.Name}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <md-action-row>
                <button md-button color="primary" (click)="actualizeRoles()>Approve</button>
            </md-action-row>
        </md-expansion-panel>
    </md-accordion>
```

This is user's roles model below where `RoleIds[]` has a table of `Ids` roles.

```
export class UserRole {
    UserId: number;

    Name: string;

    RoleName: string;
    RoleIds: number[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="variable">
```

You can read more here:

[Angular 2 Checkbox Two Way Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214655/angular-2-checkbox-two-way-data-binding)