# Dynamic input of type checkbox in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have the following code

```
<input [type]="'checkbox'" [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
<p>Value: {{ inputValue }}</p>
```

Can somebody explain why the value in `inputValue` does not change?

I can't set just `type="checkbox"` because I have dynamic type of input.

It works fine when type is `text` or `number`. It also works when the type of input is static (`type="checkbox"`)

Comment: i would not set the type dynamically but rather render one or the other with `*ngIf`

Comment: Is your intent to show Value: true (or false)?

Comment: @tt9 yes, I want `inputValue` to change when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40214714/2313300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dynamically setting the input type does not work why don't you try an `ngSwitch` with a static input type for checkbox?

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="inputType">
    <input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
    <input *ngSwitchDefault [type]="inputType" [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
</ng-container>
```

Check out this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-input-type).

Comment: Thank you.I ended up doing this. Strange that this doesn't work out of the box.