# How to add recursively numbers before input value

Tags: javascript, angular

This is probably very much a newbie question -- but i can't figure it out.

I have an input text with `minlegth` 9, and I have to do something like this:

If the user types only one number, I have to add some `"0"` before this number to reach `value.length == 9`

```
Example:
123 => 000000123
```

I'm using Angular 2 input forms and a pipe to transform the result.

Can anyone help?

---

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros) i've found the solution:**

```
transform(val) {
        var standardLength = "000000000";
        return (standardLength + val).slice(-standardLength.length);
    }
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transform(val){
    let zeros = "000000000";
    return zeros.concat(val).slice(Math.min(val.toString().length * -1,-9));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number=("0".repeat(9)+number).substr(-9);
```

Simply apply this to the inputs value on change.

Answer (score 0):

If the length you want is always static (here 9), this is the easiest method.

```js
num = [1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(("000000000" + num[i]).substr(-9,9));
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not optimal.

You can use the `Slice()` method to put into your string whatever you want.

I.E.:

```
('0' + '').slice(-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pad(num, size) {
     var s = num+"";
     while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
     return s;
}

// usage
pad(123, 9)
```