# Filtering specific data and getting error Can't bind to 'ngModel'

Tags: angular, filter, pipe, angular-ngmodel

I tried to filter the products using a pipe (if no filter choosing from the list I will show all the products)
But I'm getting an error. why?

```
<h2>store</h2>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name=Gender>
      <option *ngFor="let g of GenderFilter">{{g.DisplayText}}</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOptionPrice" name=Price>
      <option *ngFor="let p of PriceFilter">{{p.DisplayText}}</option>
    </select>
    <tr *ngFor="let P of products | filer : Gender | orderBy: 'GenderFilter'">
      <td>{{p.DisplayText}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let P of products | filer : Price | orderBy: 'PriceFilter'">
      <td>{{p.DisplayText}}</td>
    </tr>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let store of stores">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let product of store.Products">
              <img src={{product.ProductImage}}>
              <p>store: {{ store.StoreName }}</p>
              <p>Product Price: {{ product.Price | currency}}</p>
            <p>Product Title: {{ product.ProductTitle }}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: @TalhaJunaidCan't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("<h2>store</h2>
<select [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name=Gender>
  <option *ngFor="let g of GenderFilter">{{g.DisplayText}}<"): ng:///AppModule/StoreComponent.html@1:8
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'.

Comment: did you import `FormsModule` inside your `*.module.ts` file??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason can be
Missing FormsModule, hence Add this to your Module,

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule      
    ]
```

or 
Check the syntax/spelling of `[(ngModel)]` in the select

Comment: Thank you! you're right. Just now the filter not working

Comment: Pipe would be best approach. but you can try this too.
<div *ng-for="#item of itemsList">
  <tr *ng-if="conditon(item)">
    // code
  </tr>
</div>

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain how to do it with pipe? thanks!

Comment: can you share a stackblitz of your work it would be easier to get the issue

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxfqwk?file=src%2Fapp%2Forderby.pipe.ts Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you!! Trying to fix it but nothing change

Comment: Hi ur stackblitz is giving error and not running , may be https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe this can help you get sorted

Comment: Thanks! I will look. can't I see  ngx-order-pipe --save?

Comment: And the diffrent is I need to show the products filtered by "price filter"I will check thanks

Comment: working code snippet:
@Pipe({
  name: "sort"
})
export class ArraySortPipe  implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}

and 

*ngFor="let myObj of myArr | sort:'fieldName'"

hope this is enough if you give a try