# Angular 6 "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'."

Tags: angular

Theres a bunch of people who already asked this question but I already followed every answer by importing it in my app.module.ts file and even imported it in app.spec.ts file

heres the html file:

```
<p>{{ randomWord }}</p>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="enteredValue">
<button (click)="onSubmit()" >Submit</button>
<p>{{ answer }}</p>
```

heres the app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';


import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,
    FormsModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score 17):

Import **FormModule** in imports instead of declarations

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
   FormsModule
  ],
```

Sample Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-stackovf?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea why I didn't catch that

Comment: @MichaelBrown Please mark it as answer if it's worked

Answer (score 5):

Adding below code in `app.module.ts` file solved my issue

Add forms import

```
import {FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

then add `FormsModule` in `@NgModule`'s import section

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```