# Template Parse Errors (only) When Running Karma Tests

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner, webstorm

I have a small angular app whose AppComponent methods I'd like to write unit tests for. My application is compiled and runs as expected, but when I try to run the default tests for it (I'm using webstorm, so I switch to `Tests` in the run/debug configurations dropdown) I'm getting a template parse error related to my `html` file. Karma reports the offending line as follows:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'. ("
      <div style="height:10px"></div>
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <textarea [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="data"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div style="height:10px"></div>
    "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@13:14
```

I had this issue when I was first getting started, because I hadn't import `FormsModule` and added it to `@NgModule` in my `app.module.ts` yet [(as in here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/5692730). Is there a test-specific place I need to add that import? I tried importing it to my `app.component.spec.ts` but that made no difference.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], are you sure you're loading the forms module in the tests?

Comment: Have you imported formsModule in unit test?

Comment: @Akhlesh that was the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `app.component.spec.ts` needed to have the FormsModule imported as well:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule  // <- important!
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```