# Ngmodel is not property of input

Tags: angular, input

I have problem using NgModel, it is not working when I want to save data from input.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
      placeholder="Account number"
      value="{{ account.number }}"
      [ERROR ->][(NgModel)]="newAccountNumber"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
```

I've already searched for solution, but only thing I found was to inport FormsModule and MatInputModule and I have those inports.

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
HttpClientModule,
MatMenuModule,
MatIconModule,
MatToolbarModule,
MatButtonModule,
MatTableModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatSelectModule,
MatCardModule,
NoopAnimationsModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule
]

<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Account number"
      value="{{ account.number }}"
      [(NgModel)]="newAccountNumber"
    />
     </mat-form-field>
```

What should I do to save data from input correctly?

Comment: FormsModule where you add?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input

Comment: @PatrykPanek is right

Comment: thank you! @PatrykPanek! it was really stupid mistake....

Comment: @PatrykPanek i'm suggest you to post in this question. If you answer then i will remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try it:**

Try ngModel instead of NgModel

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Account number"
      value="{{ account.number }}"
      [(ngModel)]="newAccountNumber"
    />
     </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(NgModel)]`. Model directive should start from lowercase

For more information take a look on Angular docs https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `FormsModule` in app.module or in the module where your component is declared.

`import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
  ...
  ]
})
```