# I need to display all the names I have written in the table in the Angular field

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I need to display all the names I have written in the table in the Angular field.

I have DB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sellers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Login] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RegistrationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
GO
```

I am requesting ASP web API to bring all the names from the table:

```
    public class SellersController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNames(string name)
            {
                using (var dataBaseContext = new DataBaseContext())
                {
                    var query = from seller in dataBaseContext.Sellers
                                where
                                seller.Name == name
                                select seller;
                    return Ok(await query.ToListAsync());
                }
            }
        }
```

I'll bring it to the angular. But it is not displayed and generally cries out the code:

```
       import { Sellers } from './sellers.model';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SellersService {

      formData : Sellers;

      constructor() { }
    }

    ________________
    <div class="p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white">
        <input name="Sellers" #Sellers="ngModel"[(ngModel)] = "service.formData" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Nothing is displayed and the last line of the code issues an error

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.Angular
```

UPD:

```
import { SellersService } from './shared/sellers.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TopRegionComponent } from './components/top-region/top-region.component';
import { LeftRegionComponent } from './components/left-region/left-region.component';
import { BottomRegionComponent } from './components/bottom-region/bottom-region.component';
import { CenterRegionComponent } from './components/center-region/center-region.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'user', component: UserComponent},
  {path: 'left-region', component: LeftRegionComponent},
  {path: 'top-region', component: TopRegionComponent},
  {path: 'bottom-region', component: BottomRegionComponent},
  {path: 'center-region', component: CenterRegionComponent},
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopRegionComponent,
    LeftRegionComponent,
    BottomRegionComponent,
    CenterRegionComponent,
    UserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [SellersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

UPD2:

```
import { SellersService } from './../../shared/sellers.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'left-region',
  templateUrl: './left-region.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-region.component.css']
})
export class LeftRegionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service : SellersService)
   {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to declare variable you want to use in HTML Page @Vova Makarovych

Comment: @Sameer 
You can give us an example of how to properly declare. I also need to name a lot. all declare?

Comment: The error means that you have to `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` in your module. Taka a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input).

Comment: Did you import the FormsModule?

Comment: Your can refer angular from following link. [RefLink](https://angular.io/docs)

Comment: @riorudo UPD see
but the mistake is still and remains. I'm not there about the Importation?

Comment: Where is your associated component code for the provided HTML template? You have provided the service code.

Comment: @RobinWebb UPD2

Comment: Are you able to create a Stackblitz?

Comment: @RobinWebb no, maybe

Comment: @RobinWebb I have not github.

Comment: @RobinWebb photo error - https://a.radikal.ru/a28/1907/2a/c8d277cefa8c.png

Comment: @RobinWebb I wrote  int Stackvlitz  in my code -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-caqpw2

Answer (score 0):

I have given an example for your query kindly look into it.

```
import { Sellers } from './sellers.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SellersService {
   formData : Sellers;
   seller : Sellers = new Sellers();
   constructor() { }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white">
<input name="Sellers" #Sellers="ngModel" [(ngModel)]= "seller.Name" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: @Sammer I wrote int Stackvlitz in my code -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-caqpw2

Comment: @Sammer 
I look at that link on the touristic that you threw. but I did not find out how to torture me in this case (((