# How to assign values in dictionary from form group through looping?

Tags: angularjs, ionic4

I am developing a mobile application that send a request to REST api, however, the data needed to pass must be in **dictionary** format. Thus, I came up with constructing an empty dictionary format like this;

`my_dict= { key_1: '', key_2: '', key_3: '', key_4: '', key_5: '', key_6: ''};`

And I'm adding value to each corresponding key by:

```
this.my_dict.key_1= this.my_form.value.value_1;
this.my_dict.key_2= this.my_form.value.value_2;
this.my_dict.key_3= this.my_form.value.value_3;
this.my_dict.key_4= this.my_form.value.value_4;
this.my_dict.key_5= this.my_form.value.value_5;
this.my_dict.key_6= this.my_form.value.value_6;
```

The value that I am assigning to are from **FormGroup**. I access each **FormControl** through `this.<form>.value.<form_control_name>`. Example: `this.my_form.value.value_1`

What I'm trying to do now is to find the most efficient way of storing values in dictionary just like by using **for loop**. Anyone know how to convert my code in a **for loop** way?

This is the entire form

```
<!-- Transportation Form -->
      <form [formGroup]="transpo_form" #f="ngForm">

        <!-- Form Item 1 (Description) -->
        <ion-item>
          <ion-input placeholder="Description (Optional)" type="text" formControlName="description" clearInput></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <!-- Form Item 2 (Location) -->
        <ion-item>
          <ion-input placeholder="Location" formControlName="location" required clearInput ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <!-- Throw an error if field is invalid -->
        <div *ngIf="!transpo_form.controls.location.valid  && (transpo_form.controls.location.dirty || submit_attempt)" class="validator-error">
          * This field is required
        </div>

        <!-- Form Item 3 (Vehicle Type) -->
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Vehicle Type</ion-label>
            <ion-select value="notifications" interface="action-sheet" formControlName="vehicle" required>
              <ion-select-option>Tricycle</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option>Bus</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option selected>Jeepney</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option>Taxi</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option>Tricycle</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option>Train</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
        <!-- Throw an error if field is invalid -->
        <div *ngIf="!transpo_form.controls.vehicle.valid  && (transpo_form.controls.vehicle.dirty || submit_attempt)" class="validator-error">
          * This field is required
        </div>
        <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Arrival Date</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime placeholder="Select Date" formControlName="arrival_date" required></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="!transpo_form.controls.arrival_date.valid  && (transpo_form.controls.arrival_date.dirty || submit_attempt)" class="validator-error">
            * This field is required
        </div>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Arrival Time</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime display-format="h:mm A" picker-format="h:mm A" placeholder="Select Time" formControlName="arrival_time" required></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="!transpo_form.controls.arrival_time.valid  && (transpo_form.controls.arrival_time.dirty || submit_attempt)" class="validator-error">
            * This field is required
        </div>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Cost" formControlName="cost" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="!transpo_form.controls.cost.valid  && (transpo_form.controls.cost.dirty || submit_attempt)" class="validator-error">
            * This field is required
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
            <ion-button color="success" expand="block" (click)="submit()">Add to my expenses</ion-button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

*Note: Sorry for noob question because I'm actually new to Ionic 4 with AngularJS as backend and I can't find a useful tutorial for this.*

Comment: you should bind your form fields to angularjs models, show us the form, maybe we can help.

Comment: I try to use ngmodels to ion input tag in my form but I always seeing this error Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Comment: Also, I already added the FormsModule in my app.component.ts as well as on the page component that I'm working on.

Comment: this should give you a headstart: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/1638261

Comment: I already follow all the answer stated there but no one work for me.