# Can't bind to ngModel because it is not being recognized

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a simple form by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nM1S7SZxc8) but i am getting following error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

this is my html HomeComponent:

```
Pokemon Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pkname">
<button mt-raised-button>Search</button>
```

this is my views module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/views/home/home.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule,FormsModule],
    exports: [HomeComponent],
    declarations: [HomeComponent]
  })
  export class ViewModule {}
```

I've also imported FormsModule in my app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Comment: i already did that. it was the first result i've found

Comment: Can you please share the app.module code also

Comment: @SRana sure, just a second

Comment: Everything looks good. Can you just cancel the current running instance using CTRL+C and re-run it ?

Comment: ok give me a second

Comment: i just did it and i am still getting the same error.

Comment: You should get an error "cannot import in 2 modules" so it's impossible you have imported FormsModule in both app and view module

Comment: @Angular nope, of course you can import the same module into 2 modules. [Here's](https://angular-ylsxou.stackblitz.io) a quick reproduction of your code and it works fine.

Comment: @Angular I can upload the entire code if you want. i am new to angular, in fact i started it yesterday so there's probably something i am doing wrong here.

Comment: It all looks good, could you upload the .ts file where you are binding the value too as well please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `ViewModule` into `AppModule`

Your app.module should look something like-

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

import { ViewModule } from "./viewmodule.module";   // your file path

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ViewModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: the error now changed to this:

Type HomeComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppRoutingModule and ViewModule! Please consider moving HomeComponent to a higher module that imports AppRoutingModule and ViewModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HomeComponent then import that NgModule in AppRoutingModule and ViewModule.

Comment: Ok, remove `HomeComponent` from `AppRoutingModule` and try

Comment: it still is on app-routing, i just removed the declarations and entryComponents and now everything is working. thanks mate.