# DataBinding in Angular

Tags: angular

I am getting error No directive found with export as ngForm

My app.module.ts

```
 import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

My imports

```
 imports: [ReactiveFormsModule,CommonModule,FormsModule]
```

LoginComponent.html

```
  <div class="row w-100 mx-0">
    <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
      <div class="auth-form-light text-left py-5 px-4 px-sm-5">
        <div class="brand-logo">
          <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
       <form class="pt-3" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="userId"  name="userId" placeholder="LogIn ID" ngModel>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="userName"  name="userPassword" placeholder="Password" ngModel>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gradient-light btn-rounded btn-fw btn-lg" routerLink="/dashboard">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

LoginComponent.ts ngForm are imported but i am getting the error that import is required formsModule and NgForm are imported and i am getting the error at npm start

```
     import{NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
     import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    arr: any[]=[];    
    onSubmit(form : NgForm) {
      this.arr = form.value
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.arr))
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import them in the order like ***BrowserModule***, ***FormsModule*** and ***ReactiveFormsModule***. Angular compiler will take them in the order what we have mentioned in Imports array of our Module class (Correct me if I am wrong).

So importing order should be from Basic to Feature modules.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule     
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can also see here in this answer which is for similar kind of question

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57849112/9764133

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you import** `BrowserModule` **in** `app.module.ts`
**like that**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

and add it to imports like that :-

imports: [
BrowserModule, <<<<<<<<<< 
FormsModule,
],
```

**that is worked for me**