# Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter

in the below code I want to use the `EventEmitter` to result in calling the method `onlyNewAddedItems`.

I defined the `EventEmitter` instance and the method that emits the event as shown below:

```
@Output() newItemValue = new EventEmitter<string>();

  addNewItem(val : string) {
    this.newItemValue.emit(val);
    console.log("add new item:" + val);
    this.items.push(val);
  }
```

To bind to third event I did the following:

```
<h1 (newItemValue) = onlyNewlyAddedItems($event)></h1>
```

but when I compile the code, I receive the following error

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:4:42 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

4 <h1 (newItemValue) = onlyNewlyAddedItems($event)></h1>                                        
  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Please, let me know how to execute the method `onlyNewlyAddedItems` via `EventEmitter`.

**AppComponent.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'InputOutputBindings';
  currentItem = 'TV';
  items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];

  @Output() newItemValue = new EventEmitter<string>();

  addNewItem(val : string) {
    this.newItemValue.emit(val);
    console.log("add new item:" + val);
    this.items.push(val);
  }

  onlyNewlyAddedItems(val : string) {
    console.log("onlyNewlyAddedItems:" + val);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<h1 #test = customdirective appItemDetails [item]="currentItem">{{currentItem}}  item</h1>
<label>Add an item: <input #newItem></label>
<button (click) = addNewItem(newItem.value)>add new item</button>
<h1 (newItemValue) = onlyNewlyAddedItems($event)></h1>
```

Comment: This error can happen also when you put the receiving function / variable in the at the parent template on the wrong child tag  - Not the child who is emitting.

Comment: This error can happen also When a typo like Wrong Output variable when emitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the error,

In the onlyNewlyAddedItems method, you are expecting string but you're passing $event from the template. Please try with the below code.

```
<h1 #test = customdirective appItemDetails [item]="currentItem">{{currentItem}}  item</h1>
<label>Add an item: <input #newItem></label>
<button (click) = addNewItem(newItem.value)>add new item</button>
<h1 (newItemValue) = onlyNewlyAddedItems(newItem.value)></h1>
```

> **But listening inside the component will not work. since these
> decorators (Input and Output) are used to communicate outside from the component.**

Comment: is being listning inside the component the reason why $event is not working!!is there anyway to have $event working?

Comment: It is not listening inside, actually, the error is related to type mismatch. Please let me know the use case, Why we need a separate event emitter to log the new item when we have the current new item and respective handle.

Comment: Welcome! @LetsamrIt

Comment: Where do you get newItem.value from?

Comment: From template variable @CharlesRobertson

Answer (score 26):

Temporary solution if you want to leave strict template type checking enabled is to wrap $event in **$any()**. Example:

**$any($event)**

it should work .. tested on Angular 13x

Comment: I would advise against going this way. It's not necessary and weakens your codebase. All typing error messages can be solved by switching to `any` but it is very rare that doing so solves a typing issue.

Answer (score 10):

I simply used a wrong variable name.

Example:
Your component.ts

```
@Output() newItemValue = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

then use a wrong name:

```
<app-my-component (WrongName)="onNewItemValue($event)" ></app-my-component> 
// 'WrongName' Parameter needs to change to newItemValue
```

Answer (score 6):

Check your **app.module.ts** file and make sure you have the components listed in your container in the declarations.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations : [
   AppComponent, 
   //your child component
],
...})
```

Comment: This fixed it for me when I was dealing with ngx-image-cropper and it's events return complex types defined in their module.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgm3nt?) demo.
Event emitters are meant for passing data to parent component.
In the example, you can see that your code works when you are emitting value from a separate child component.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answers before, this error often boils down to a typo or something similar you have missed. For all of you who stumble across that error (that in my opinion should be handled better by the compiler by providing a more meaningful error message), here is other things that caused that error in my projects:

- Make sure the includes in your component are actually valid. Like `templateUrl` and `styleUrls`
- Double check that you have added the component that provides the output parameters to the `@NgModule` `declarations` section in your module. The **correct** module, that is. Angular will complain about it emitting an Event datatype because it does not know about your component.
- Make sure you have spelled the component selector correctly - in your component, and when using it in the parent. I have experienced this error message when using a component selector that does not exist at all. Believe me, it cost me hours to figure that out. A classic: Forgetting the `app-` prefix when using the component.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have already pointed out, the most likely cause is an error in your declarations/exports/imports in your module, so check that first. However, if you can't seem to fix the issues, here's a handy work around (that doesn't use 'any', which you should try to avoid using).

Step 1 - emit your data as an event in your child ts component:

```js
@Output() newItemValue = new EventEmitter<Event>();

//...

this.newItemValue.emit(result as unknown as Event);
```

Step 2 - Your parent html component is the same as what you already have:

```html
<h1 (newItemValue) = onlyNewlyAddedItems($event)></h1>
```

Step 3 - your parent ts component will convert the payload into the necessary data type:

```js
  onlyNewlyAddedItems(event: Event) {
    const val = event as unknown as string;
    console.log(`onlyNewlyAddedItems:  ${val}`);
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have omitted this error by adding the following code in **app.module.ts** file

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

[...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]
    FormsModule
  ],
  [...]
})
```

For more information [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score -1):

```
onlyNewlyAddedItems(val: string) {
console.log("onlyNewlyAddedItems:" + val);
}
```

Change the method parameter datatype from **string** to **any** as below. This method works for me.

```
onlyNewlyAddedItems(val : any) {
console.log("onlyNewlyAddedItems:" + val);
}
```

Comment: losing the typing support is never a good solution in Typescript

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to handle the emitted event in the same component that you emit it from. If I remove everything else from your `AppComponent` it looks like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

  @Output() newItemValue = new EventEmitter<string>();

  # Trigger event to be emitted
  addNewItem(val : string) {
    this.newItemValue.emit(val);
  }

  # Attempt to handle event (in the same component?)
  onlyNewlyAddedItems(val : string) {
    console.log("onlyNewlyAddedItems:" + val);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- You're emitting the event here -->
<button (click) = addNewItem(newItem.value)>add item</button>

<!-- and trying to capture the event here, 
     in the same component. This won't work -->
<h1 (newItemValue) = onlyNewlyAddedItems($event)></h1>
```

Your event emitter and handler are both in the same component which I imagine is not what you want. An event is a way of communicating data to parent components.

#### Your event will be emitted from the AppComponent itself

Your event will not be emitted within the component. It will be emitted on the component, i.e. you would capture it from the app component itself:

```html
<app-component(newItemValue)="onNewItem($event)"></app-component>
```

#### Why you're seeing the wrong event type: `Event`

You can add any made up event handler to any html element and Angular will just assume it's there and cast it to `Event`. So you think that your typing is wrong but what's acutally happened is that you've added an event handler for an event that may not (probably doesn't) exist.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
@Output("addNewItem") newItemValue = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

that solved a similar problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

you're in strict mode, just wrap the $event in $any. it'll solve the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).