# Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (" <div class="input-group">*

Tags: angular

After updating to angular 12 , i am getting below error.

project is building and running , but whenever i am trying **ng test** for unit testing , i am getting below errors

*Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("*

i tried importing
**import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';** but
still same error . please help me on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import those modules into your module where the current component is located via adding a reference to then into `imports` array.

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, <====
    ReactiveFormsModule <====
  ],
  ...
});
```

Recompile the project, it should work now.
Note that just adding the import this way: `import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'` won't solve your problem because the module does not know about them, therefore `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` won't be inserted into your bundle after compilation.

Comment: i already tried this , but still same error.    
                                                                              @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,   
    ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports:[
    RouterModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ProductListService,
    PackageService,
    AuthService,
    UserService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

Comment: Try to import `CommonModule` and `BrowserModule` as well

Comment: i already imported CommonModule and BrowserModule , but still same error i am facing . Any idea to solve this , please help out , me stuck in the project.  in this project we have server-side rendering ,

Comment: interesting... I'd like to see the html part where you specify the input and ngModule

Comment: my project is running but  whenever i am trying ng-test for unit testing . i am getting above errors. i updated question also .