# Erreur: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. Besoin d'aide

Tags: angular, ngmodel

Here I still have this error, I did what I found on the doc and on the forums but I have to miss something. Can someone help me

Erreur:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cct2.png
App.module.ts:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRMvX.png
LoginComponent:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K22xF.png

EDIT:
I forget to import my loginComponent ‍♂️

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Comment: `loginComponent` is not listed in the declaration of  `app.module`. thats why you are getting this error

Comment: yesss thanks a lot @Edison, I just saw that, I was focus on the FormsModule than I missed to include my loginComponent ‍♂️. I feel stupid. Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please import  your `LoginComponent` into `app.module.ts` and update `declarations` array

```
declarations: [
     AppComponent, 
     HomeComponent,
     WelcomeComponent,
     LoginComponent //added
  ],
```