# Why is Angular not recognizing FormsModule?

Tags: angular

Angular is giving me the following errors even though I have FormsModule imported.

```
Error: src/app/user/user.component.html:9:26 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 
'ngForm'.

<form #signinForm="ngForm">

                      
Error: src/app/user/user.component.html:25:48 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it 
isn't a known property of 'input'.

title="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" #password="ngModel" 
name='password' required>
```

I have FormsModule imported in user.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

I also tried importing it in app.modules to no avail.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input

Comment: @Deepak I have used that syntax in numerous applications. I believed I got it from angular.io.

Comment: This is from angular.io hero application: <form #heroForm="ngForm" appIdentityRevealed>

Comment: has you re-init the `ng serve`? it's looks like fine. BTW check if you has a variable in your .ts with the same name. I don't know what more can be happened :(. NOTE @DeepakJha, yes, it's used in template driven forms -forms that use [(ngModel)]-

Comment: Yeah, Eliseo, I am actually using ng build so I have rebuilt many times but the problem still exists.