# How to fix error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'?

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

I have the following error although I imported the FormsModule in app.module.ts ans I don't know how to solve it.[Here is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izlfV.png)

I tried to import everything related to forms but the error has not gone yet.[Here is an image of app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzUaG.png)

Comment: create-user is not part of app-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)