# Angular Language Service - can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' for version 16

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-language-service

I use Angular version 16 and VScode, the code is running properly but I got this error:

```
can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
```

. I have **app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { ProductsModule } from './modules/products/products.module';
import { SalesModule } from './modules/sales/sales.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, ProductsModule, SalesModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './components/not-found/not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'sales', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/sales/sales.module').then(m => m.SalesModule) },
  { path: 'products', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/products/products.module').then(m => m.ProductsModule) },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and here is **sales.modules.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SalesRoutingModule } from './sales-routing.module';
import { AddSaleComponent } from 'src/app/components/sales/add-sale/add-sale.component';
import { SalesService } from 'src/app/services/sales.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddSaleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    SalesRoutingModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [SalesService]
})
export class SalesModule { }
```

also here is **sales-routing.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddSaleComponent } from 'src/app/components/sales/add-sale/add-sale.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AddSaleComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class SalesRoutingModule {}
```

so, in **add-sale.component.html** , I've got an error for a simple ngModel:

```
Favorite Color: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="favoriteColor">
```

and here is **add-sale.component.html.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-sale',
  templateUrl: './add-sale.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-sale.component.scss'],
})
export class AddSaleComponent {
  favoriteColor = '';
  
}
```

I've already checked [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input) but still got the error. Do you have any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** I removed PrdocutsModule and SalesModule from appModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but still does not work.

Comment: What error You have? You only posted link to another thread, not the actual error. And, btw, BrowserModule must be imported only once, in `AppModule`

Comment: Correct, lazy modules should import only CommonModule. About the error, I think it is in the title

Comment: seems all good with Francesco suggestion, exept for add-sale.component.html.ts name, are you sure that the component in error is **AddSaleComponent**? maybe is another one

Answer (score 0):

You should not import your lazy modules in the appComponent:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, ProductsModule, SalesModule],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As doing so will eagerly load them, no more lazily loaded.

Comment: I removed it, but still have the same error

Comment: Did you try re-adding the modules (lazy ones) and also add FormModule to the appModule? You import it but not include in the imports array.

Comment: I updated the question, please let me know if I miss something.

Comment: I do not see FormsModule in the import:[] array in AppModule

Comment: I added it in update's section

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue:
https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/1894

To resolve the problem , you should update VSCode and then reload Angular Language Service to have the same version (16). Good to know that, they removed ngcc, more information is here:
https://itnext.io/angular-16-is-huge-67288a3ff58b