# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select' in angular cli 17.2.3

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngmodel

I want to create a dashboard page where the admin can create accounts for teachers, students, and respondents. When the admin selects the account type, a specific form will appear on the same page. I tried using ngModel, but I encountered the error mentioned above

> create-accounts.component.ts

```
    <section class="p-6 rounded-md bg-slate-400 mt-4">
        <h1 class="mb-2 text-3xl">creer comptes</h1>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectAccount" name="selectAccount">
            <option value="student"  selected>etudiant</option>
            <option value="teacher" >enseignant</option>
            <option value="resp">responsable</option>
        </select>

        <div *ngIf="selectAccount === student">
            <app-student-form></app-student-form>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="selectAccount === teacher">
            <app-teacher-form></app-teacher-form>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="selectAccount === resp">
            <app-resp-form></app-resp-form>
        </div>
    </section
```

> create-accounts-component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TeacherFormComponent } from '../../components/form-components/teacher-form/teacher-form.component';
import { StudentFormComponent } from '../../components/form-components/student-form/student-form.component';
import { RespFormComponent } from '../../components/form-components/resp-form/resp-form.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-accounts',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FontAwesomeModule, TeacherFormComponent, StudentFormComponent, RespFormComponent,],
  templateUrl: './create-accounts.component.html',
  styleUrl: './create-accounts.component.css'
})

export class CreateAccountsComponent {
  selectAccount= "student-form";
}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { RecoverPasswordComponent } from './pages/recover-password/recover-password.component';
import { CreateAccountsComponent } from './pages/admin/administrator/create-accounts/create-accounts.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, LoginComponent, RecoverPasswordComponent, CreateAccountsComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
}
```

Comment: I don't see the `FormsModule` being imported anywhere here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896469/3000206

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, but where? i don't have app.module.ts, i searched before, all those who had the same problem have app.module.ts, but i use the angular 17

Comment: I'll admit, I haven't used standalone components yet, but I'm assuming it would go in the `imports`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you, you were right, sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import FormsModule in create-accounts-component.ts like FontAwesomeModule

Comment: thank you very much, since ngModel working and i have imported ngIf, i get this error message: ` Property 'student' does not exist on type 'CreateAccountsComponent'` do you have any idea why? thank u in advance

Comment: In the ngIf condition you are using 2 properties (selectAccount and student) that must be defined in create-accounts-component.ts, if you are trying to compare the selectAccount property with the string "student" then the code should be selectAccount ===  "student"