# Angular 2 ngModel two way binding

Tags: angular

I was trying to test the two way binding of Angular2 but I'm always getting this

error: **Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.**

How can I solve this ?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'impure-pipe',
  template: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]='a'> <p>{{ a| calcPipe:b}}</p>`
})
export class PipesAppComponent {

  a: number = 2;
  b: number = 2;

}
```

Comment: duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880150/angular-2-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says on this page [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel) from the Angular 2 web site

> Before we can use the ngModel directive in a two-way data binding, we must import the FormsModule and add it to the Angular module's imports list. Learn more about the FormsModule and ngModel in the Forms chapter.

Do you have the `FormsModule` imported in your `app.module.ts`?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import the `FormsModule`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a definition of `FormsModule` in app.module.ts?

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
```