# Angular Js 2 - Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to use the Reactive Forms of Angular js 2 and I have imported both Formcontrol and ReactiveFormsModule in my component but I am having this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuueZ.jpg)

[Product.component.ts]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880150/angular-2-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Comment: Please add more code describing your situation. Paste component.ts and component.html files here.

Answer (score 2):

This is not technically a duplicate, since in the question that has been marked as a duplicate, is about needing to mark FormsModule in `ngModule`. But the case is similar. You need to mark the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `ngModule`, not the component.

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, ....],
  // ....
})
```