# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 4.2.4 and I am getting an error in the console :

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

while I include FormsModule in file app.module.ts like as

```
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...APP_LAYOUTS,
    ...APP_COMPONENTS,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and by html code is as

```
<form id="user-add-form">
    <div class="text-center m-t-10"><span class="login-img"><i class="ti-check-box"></i></span></div>
    <h3 class="login-title">Add New User</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" [(ngModel)]="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" [(ngModel)]="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password_confirmation" [(ngModel)]="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and some component file code is

```
import { FormBuilder,Validator } from '@angular/forms';
export class UserAddComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    password_confirmation: string;
```

I already see the below links but not get any solutions

[Angular 4 - "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' " error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-4-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

[Angular 2: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880150/angular-2-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

[Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

please help to resolve it

Comment: Please add code of `@NgModule` where `UserAddComponent` is declared. You have to import FormsModule there or import module that exports FormsModule

Answer (score 7):

From Wiki,

> This error often means that you haven't declared the directive "x" or
>   haven't imported the NgModule to which "x" belongs.
>
> You also get this error if "x" really isn't a property or if "x" is a
>   private component property (i.e., lacks the @Input or @Output
>   decorator).
>
> For example, if "x" is ngModel, you may not have imported the
>   FormsModule from @angular/forms.
>
> Perhaps you declared "x" in an application feature module but forgot
>   to export it? The "x" class isn't visible to other components of other
>   NgModules until you add it to the exports list

So just import 'FormsModule' in 'UserAddComponent'

`import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';`

Hope it helps !!