# Angular 5 - Trying to add ngModel to a standalone input causes errors

Tags: angular

I have a standalone input that I'm trying to use with `[(ngModel)]`, yet when I try to use it, I'm getting this error:

```
core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

Here is the template code for the input:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" [(ngModel)]="howMuchToSell">
```

I've even tried this:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="howMuchToSell">
```

But I then get a different error saying [ngModelOptions] is not a known property.

In my `app.module` file, I'm including `FormsModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AuthGuard],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

These are my dependencies in my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "node-bittrex-api": "^0.8.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "yarn": "^1.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.6.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.51",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

Yet I'm still getting this issue? I'm so confused :(

Comment: try to recompile your project

Comment: Seems similar issue of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687958/uncaught-error-template-parse-errors-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a/

Comment: I tried doing this and am still running into the error hmmm

Comment: Are you lazy loading any other modules?

Comment: I'm using a starter project I found that has a lot of this stuff implemented already: https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-5 - I'm not entirely sure, since I'm not hip with Angular 5 stuff as of yet

Comment: You need to import `FormsModule` directly in the module where declared your component in which you're using `ngModel`.

Comment: You're right. I realized that there are multiple modules in this project. I found the module for the component I was loading the code in, added the appropriate module and it worked :)